# Is it bead art or beads art? (Popular Usage)

Tags: word-choice, word-usage, popularity

It seems that both terms are used to refer to beadwork but beads art seems really weird to me (think Dogs Food).

To be clear, I am not only referring to the rules of usage. I would like to know what is the most common usage - this is important for us as we need to use the preferred copy in our prints. If "bead art" is technically correct, but most people don't resonate with the term, then we would still go with "beads art". Most of the people in my company insist that it's "beads art". I think it's "bead".

Comment: [Google Ngram Viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=bead+art%2Cbeads+art&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cbead%20art%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cbead%20art%3B%2Cc0) says there's no result for "beads art". [This link](http://www.google.com/search?q=%22bead%20art%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en) shows a broad range of books that use the term "bead art". Tell your colleagues they've got it wrong, both for correctness and for common usage. :-)

Comment: Thank you very much! I did not think to use Google Ngram Viewer.